# How to access drive on linux

Tags: linux, ssh

I have scientific linux(Scientific Linux release 6.6 (Carbon)) installed on my company desktop. When I perform "df -h" I am able to see a drive of 1.8TB attached to it, but as shown below I am not able to access it. How can I access this drive from my system -- as I am at a different location, therefore as of now I can only remotely login into my system using ssh.

```
[systeml@sys ~]$ df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                     32G  248K   32G   1% /dev
tmpfs                        32G   68K   32G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/vg_sys-lv_root   50G  8.5G   39G  19% /
/dev/sdb1                   477M   91M  361M  21% /boot
/dev/sdc                    1.8T  206G  1.5T  12% /media/26f2d706-0a83-4352-9b4d-832fae11e8eb
[systeml@sys ~]$ cd /media/26f2d706-0a83-4352-9b4d-832fae11e8eb/
[systeml@sys 26f2d706-0a83-4352-9b4d-832fae11e8eb]$ ls
ls: reading directory .: Input/output error
[systeml@sys 26f2d706-0a83-4352-9b4d-832fae11e8eb]$ cd /dev/sdc
-bash: cd: /dev/sdc: Not a directory
```

Output of "`ls -la /var/log`" is:

```
total 85892
drwxr-xr-x. 16 root  root     12288 Jul 10 03:33 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root  root      4096 May 14  2013 ..
-rw-------.  1 root  root     18682 May 14  2013 anaconda.ifcfg.log
-rw-------.  1 root  root     22111 May 14  2013 anaconda.log
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1136574 May 14  2013 anaconda.program.log
-rw-------.  1 root  root    198308 May 14  2013 anaconda.storage.log
-rw-------.  1 root  root    101580 May 14  2013 anaconda.syslog
-rw-------.  1 root  root     38412 May 14  2013 anaconda.xlog
-rw-------.  1 root  root    181013 May 14  2013 anaconda.yum.log
drwxr-x---.  2 root  root      4096 Mar  4 16:34 audit
-rw-r--r--.  2 root  root      3515 Apr 25 09:58 boot.log
-rw-------.  1 root  utmp      2304 Jul 10 14:06 btmp
-rw-------.  1 root  utmp      3072 Jul  1 00:23 btmp-20150701
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root      4096 May 14  2013 ConsoleKit
-rw-------.  1 root  root    146507 Jul 11 21:10 cron
-rw-------.  1 root  root     14894 Nov 16  2014 cron-20141019.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     14851 Nov 16  2014 cron-20141026.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15036 Nov 16  2014 cron-20141102.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15152 Nov 16  2014 cron-20141109.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15021 Nov 23  2014 cron-20141116.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15016 Nov 30  2014 cron-20141123.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15061 Dec  7  2014 cron-20141130.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15292 Dec 14  2014 cron-20141207.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     14970 Dec 21  2014 cron-20141214.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15070 Dec 28  2014 cron-20141221.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15089 Jan  4  2015 cron-20141228.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15096 Jan 11 03:49 cron-20150104.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15107 Jan 18 03:43 cron-20150111.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15115 Jan 25 03:34 cron-20150118.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15032 Feb  1 04:07 cron-20150125.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15374 Feb  8 03:49 cron-20150201.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     14978 Feb 15 03:22 cron-20150208.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15090 Feb 22 03:48 cron-20150215.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15148 Mar  1 03:26 cron-20150222.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15243 Mar  8 03:18 cron-20150301.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15687 Mar 15 03:37 cron-20150308.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15032 Mar 22 03:16 cron-20150315.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15178 Mar 29 04:49 cron-20150322.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15333 Apr  5 03:22 cron-20150329.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     14895 Apr 12 03:51 cron-20150405.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15903 Apr 19 03:10 cron-20150412.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     17385 Apr 26 03:22 cron-20150419.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     16502 May  3 03:09 cron-20150426.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15260 May 10 03:50 cron-20150503.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15292 May 17 03:22 cron-20150510.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15366 May 24 03:38 cron-20150517.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15243 May 31 03:29 cron-20150524.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15405 Jun  7 03:44 cron-20150531.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15529 Jun 14 03:16 cron-20150607.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15275 Jun 21 03:23 cron-20150614.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15232 Jun 28 03:12 cron-20150621.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     15386 Jul  5 03:19 cron-20150628.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root    153616 Jul  5 03:19 cron-20150705
drwxr-xr-x.  2 lp    sys       4096 Jun 18 01:32 cups
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root     86133 Apr 25 09:57 dmesg
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root     60444 Mar  4 19:07 dmesg.old
-rw-------.  1 root  root         0 Apr 23 03:10 dracut.log
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root    351736 May 14  2013 dracut.log-20140101
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root    192285 Apr 22 06:37 dracut.log-20150423
drwxrwx--T.  2 root  gdm       4096 Apr 29 10:59 gdm
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root      4096 Oct 14  2014 glusterfs
drwx------.  2 root  root     12288 Jul  5 03:19 httpd
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root  root      4096 Jul  2  2013 IBM_Support
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root    147168 Jul 11 20:43 lastlog
-rw-------.  1 root  root      4452 Jul 11 03:23 maillog
-rw-------.  1 root  root       829 Nov 16  2014 maillog-20141019.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       789 Nov 16  2014 maillog-20141026.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       718 Nov 16  2014 maillog-20141102.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1005 Nov 16  2014 maillog-20141109.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       925 Nov 23  2014 maillog-20141116.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       778 Nov 30  2014 maillog-20141123.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       842 Dec  7  2014 maillog-20141130.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       867 Dec 14  2014 maillog-20141207.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       982 Dec 21  2014 maillog-20141214.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       841 Dec 28  2014 maillog-20141221.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       781 Jan  4  2015 maillog-20141228.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       721 Jan 11 03:49 maillog-20150104.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       781 Jan 18 03:43 maillog-20150111.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       793 Jan 25 03:34 maillog-20150118.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       866 Feb  1 04:07 maillog-20150125.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       958 Feb  8 03:49 maillog-20150201.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       704 Feb 15 03:22 maillog-20150208.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       788 Feb 22 03:48 maillog-20150215.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       711 Mar  1 03:26 maillog-20150222.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       893 Mar  8 03:18 maillog-20150301.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1048 Mar 15 03:37 maillog-20150308.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1045 Mar 22 03:16 maillog-20150315.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       803 Mar 29 04:49 maillog-20150322.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       792 Apr  5 03:22 maillog-20150329.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       864 Apr 12 03:51 maillog-20150405.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       983 Apr 19 03:10 maillog-20150412.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       951 Apr 26 03:22 maillog-20150419.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1011 May  3 03:09 maillog-20150426.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       743 May 10 03:50 maillog-20150503.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       751 May 17 03:22 maillog-20150510.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       967 May 24 03:38 maillog-20150517.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       723 May 31 03:29 maillog-20150524.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       809 Jun  7 03:44 maillog-20150531.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       814 Jun 14 03:16 maillog-20150607.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1451 Jun 21 03:23 maillog-20150614.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       870 Jun 28 03:12 maillog-20150621.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       717 Jul  5 03:19 maillog-20150628.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      5014 Jul  5 03:19 maillog-20150705
-rw-------.  1 root  root  26775198 Jul 11 21:15 messages
-rw-------.  1 root  root       254 Nov 16  2014 messages-20141019.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       460 Nov 16  2014 messages-20141026.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       405 Nov 16  2014 messages-20141102.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      5565 Nov 16  2014 messages-20141109.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      6020 Nov 23  2014 messages-20141116.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       193 Nov 30  2014 messages-20141123.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       142 Dec  7  2014 messages-20141130.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       278 Dec 14  2014 messages-20141207.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       302 Dec 21  2014 messages-20141214.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       250 Dec 28  2014 messages-20141221.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       538 Jan  4  2015 messages-20141228.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       141 Jan 11 03:49 messages-20150104.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       238 Jan 18 03:43 messages-20150111.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root       231 Jan 25 03:34 messages-20150118.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root    634783 Feb  1 04:07 messages-20150125.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1004690 Feb  8 03:49 messages-20150201.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root    998003 Feb 15 03:22 messages-20150208.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root    996750 Feb 22 03:48 messages-20150215.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1002053 Mar  1 03:26 messages-20150222.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1010598 Mar  8 03:18 messages-20150301.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1021663 Mar 15 03:37 messages-20150308.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1001878 Mar 22 03:16 messages-20150315.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root    997756 Mar 29 04:49 messages-20150322.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1009314 Apr  5 03:22 messages-20150329.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root    991828 Apr 12 03:52 messages-20150405.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1004507 Apr 19 03:10 messages-20150412.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1000797 Apr 26 03:22 messages-20150419.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1023182 May  3 03:09 messages-20150426.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1005502 May 10 03:50 messages-20150503.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1013400 May 17 03:22 messages-20150510.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1002643 May 24 03:38 messages-20150517.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1051169 May 31 03:29 messages-20150524.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1001413 Jun  7 03:44 messages-20150531.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1018589 Jun 14 03:16 messages-20150607.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1002525 Jun 21 03:23 messages-20150614.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1001180 Jun 28 03:12 messages-20150621.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root   1005196 Jul  5 03:19 messages-20150628.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root  28125861 Jul  5 03:19 messages-20150705
-rw-r-----.  1 mysql mysql        0 Apr  8  2014 mysqld.log
drwxr-xr-x.  2 ntp   ntp       4096 Dec 21  2014 ntpstats
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root        89 Apr 25 09:58 pm-powersave.log
drwx------.  2 root  root      4096 Nov 24  2010 ppp
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root      4096 Aug 19  2013 prelink
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root      4096 Jul 11 00:00 sa
drwx------.  3 root  root      4096 Feb 23 16:41 samba
-rw-------.  1 root  root     48723 Jul 11 21:12 secure
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1616 Nov 16  2014 secure-20141019.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1681 Nov 16  2014 secure-20141026.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2871 Nov 16  2014 secure-20141102.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2835 Nov 16  2014 secure-20141109.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2025 Nov 23  2014 secure-20141116.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1764 Nov 30  2014 secure-20141123.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2065 Dec  7  2014 secure-20141130.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2093 Dec 14  2014 secure-20141207.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2348 Dec 21  2014 secure-20141214.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1847 Dec 28  2014 secure-20141221.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1879 Jan  4  2015 secure-20141228.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1757 Jan 11 03:49 secure-20150104.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1921 Jan 18 03:43 secure-20150111.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1972 Jan 25 03:34 secure-20150118.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1647 Feb  1 04:07 secure-20150125.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2319 Feb  8 03:49 secure-20150201.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1863 Feb 15 03:22 secure-20150208.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1850 Feb 22 03:48 secure-20150215.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1877 Mar  1 03:26 secure-20150222.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2317 Mar  8 03:18 secure-20150301.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      3657 Mar 15 03:37 secure-20150308.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      3410 Mar 22 03:16 secure-20150315.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2371 Mar 29 04:49 secure-20150322.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1885 Apr  5 03:22 secure-20150329.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2880 Apr 12 03:52 secure-20150405.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      7330 Apr 19 03:10 secure-20150412.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      3882 Apr 26 03:22 secure-20150419.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      4571 May  3 03:09 secure-20150426.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2653 May 10 03:50 secure-20150503.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2947 May 17 03:22 secure-20150510.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      4934 May 24 03:38 secure-20150517.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      3239 May 31 03:29 secure-20150524.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      3443 Jun  7 03:44 secure-20150531.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2718 Jun 14 03:16 secure-20150607.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      5658 Jun 21 03:23 secure-20150614.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      2487 Jun 28 03:12 secure-20150621.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root      3477 Jul  5 03:19 secure-20150628.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     31673 Jul  5 02:08 secure-20150705
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root  root      4096 Jul  2  2013 SEP_Support
-rw-------.  1 root  root      1097 Mar 14  2014 spice-vdagent.log
-rw-------.  1 root  root         0 Nov  9  2014 spooler
-rw-------.  1 root  root         0 Oct 12  2014 spooler-20141019
-rw-------.  1 root  root         0 Oct 19  2014 spooler-20141026
-rw-------.  1 root  root         0 Oct 26  2014 spooler-20141102
-rw-------.  1 root  root         0 Nov  2  2014 spooler-20141109
drwxr-x---.  2 root  root      4096 Oct 14  2014 sssd
-rw-------.  1 root  root         0 May 14  2013 tallylog
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root         0 May 14  2013 wpa_supplicant.log
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root  utmp    158976 Jul 11 21:13 wtmp
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root  utmp   1069440 Jul 10 03:30 wtmp-20150710
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root   4502698 Jul 11 21:14 Xorg.0.log
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root    297060 Apr 29 10:59 Xorg.0.log.old
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root     17348 Jul  2  2013 Xorg.1.log
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root     17348 Jul  2  2013 Xorg.1.log.old
-rw-r--r--.  1 root  root     39023 May 14  2013 Xorg.9.log
-rw-------.  1 root  root     21186 Jul 10 05:46 yum.log
-rw-------.  1 root  root      3798 Jan  1  2015 yum.log-20140101.gz
-rw-------.  1 root  root     55818 Dec 21  2014 yum.log-20150101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/dev/sdc` is representing the hardware, it's not a directory, its mounted on `/media/26f2d706-0a83-4352-9b4d-832fae11e8eb` according the `df -h` result, so if you do `cd /media/26f2d706-0a83-4352-9b4d-832fae11e8eb` you are on the disk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried...as mentioned in my question but I got..ls: reading directory .: Input/output error

Comment: @user468261 sorry, didn't notice that, please put here result of `fdisk -l`

Comment: I have posted its output in my question

Comment: well it looks like the `/dev/sdc` is not mounted properly, try umounting it and mounting it back. Are you sure there is filesystem?

Comment: Actually it looks like it has been disconnected altogether, as `fdisk` should show it even if it's not mounted.

Comment: i am not sure if there is a file system..as it is my company's system...how can I find if there is a file system or not...

Comment: @user468261 see my comment above, I realized that it looks like the device is no more connected, so probably someone has disconnected it.

Comment: ok...thank u..can I somehow find out ..when it got disconnected..i mean the date?

Comment: it should be in `/var/log/syslog`, try `cat /var/log/syslog | grep /dev/sdc`

Comment: it gives me..cat: /var/log/syslog: No such file or directory

Comment: hmm, could you post result of `ls -la /var/log`? What linux distribution is it?

Comment: its scientific linux

Comment: i have posted its output

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you already mentioned distro in question. It's based on RedHat which I don't know so well, but try `cat /var/log/messages | grep /dev/sdc` or  `cat /var/log/lastlog | grep /dev/sdc`

Comment: none of them gave any output

Comment: It could also happen in the past, so try the same `cat /var/log/messages | grep /dev/sdc` but for different messages files you can see in there. Start with the newest -20150705 and work backwards